# More consistency with the search result count for deleted posts

Tags: bug, status-completed, search, user-interface, deleted-posts

I know I'll kinda shoot myself in my own foot there, but let's see.

As we all know:

- 10k users can *see* deleted posts. For questions, this only works when they have the URL to it.
- Mods can *see* deleted posts and also *search* for them.

However, the `deleted` operator still somehow works for 10k users. Let's search for a URL that I know has several spam posts deleted: `deleted:1 url:*teesupport*`

[image]

Now, what's going on here? There are two "live" answers. What's with the rest of them? Why do you tell me that there are 14 search results and only show me two?

How can we resolve this? There are two options:

> 1. Allow 10k users (or maybe 15k, or 20k) to effectively search for deleted posts, thus in this case showing the twelve deleted ones as well. That might be another feature-request.
> 2. Don't allow the `deleted` operator for searches when it clearly doesn't work. Instead, **show the actual result count** and at least tell me how many deleted posts were not shown.
>
>    [image]

The latter would be incredibly useful to make a better case when searching for spam, thus flagging more effectively, wasting less time for moderators.

Answer (score 5):

The result count being off was a bug...a build just went out correcting this, it will be as if the `deleted` operator is completely ignored now, as intended.

Comment: Can't you still show how many deleted there are or was that never intended?

Comment: @slhck - nope, not intended...too many issues with users and deleted content, we decided not to allow this, we debated even enabling functionality on it for moderators.